How to do API versioning with Quart-Schema, but not in URL
How to make good OpenAPI documentation for an API, which does not have version information in the URL but uses query string parameter?
@app.route("/example-route/", methods=["GET"])
@validate_headers(AuthHeaders)
@validate_querystring(UserQueryParams)
@validate_response(UserResponse, 200)
@validate_response(ErrorResponse, 401)
async def example_api(query_args: UserQueryParams, headers: AuthHeaders):
   version = query_args.version 
   ...

This is using Quart-Schema (and Pydantic, if that matters). In the above, UserQueryParams, UserResponse, etc, should be functions of the version, not some kind of union for all versions.
It is probably possible to have some middleware to change URL routing, but then OpenAPI will show wrong URL.
Or maybe some kind of custom predicate can be made?
@app.route("/example-route/", methods=["GET"])
@validate_headers(AuthHeaders)
@validate_querystring(UserQueryParams)
@validate_response(UserResponse, 200)
@validate_response(ErrorResponse, 401)
@if_qs_param(v=1)
async def example_api_v1(query_args: UserQueryParams, headers: AuthHeaders):
   version = query_args.version 
   ...

@app.route("/example-route/", methods=["GET"])   # <-- note same URL
@validate_headers(AuthHeaders2)
@validate_querystring(UserQuery2Params)
@validate_response(UserResponse2, 200)
@validate_response(ErrorResponse, 401)
@if_qs_param(v=2)
async def example_api_v2(query_args: UserQuery2Params, headers: AuthHeaders2):
   version = query_args.version 
   ...

Any ideas?
